# using segments on default controllers in codeigniter to go to profiles after not finding the other controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, controller, segments

Does anyone know if it's possible to use segments on the default controller?

For example if i want to go to a profile on my site, it would be site.com/profileName, i know you would use it to access other controllers but I want it work so that if codeigniter can't access any controllers by what is entered in the segment, then i'd like it to look for a matching profile name from a MySQL table and then access the correct profile page and if it fails to find a match then the page will not exist, anyone have any idea on how i'd go about doing this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is `routes`

open your `application/config/routes.php`

Youc could set `(:any)` like this

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1';
```

here you can use the wildcard `any`. That if anything is entered it will direct to the controller you want it to be redirected the `$1` holds the value of the segment you entered.

then on your method just do the usual query if exist or not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is changing where the 404 error go, and catch things from there to either show 404 error, or show a profile page.